# Adding authorization header cause android to throw a filenotfound exception

Tags: android

When I add an authorization header, android throws a filenotfound exception. If I remove the

```
con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

all is well?

```
con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            String userpass = userNameEditText.getText() + ":" +  passwordEditText.getText();

            String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't verify why it works, but try do the following

From http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html use the following code

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

   });
 }
```

after you do so, there is no need to add the Authorization header, since this class will add it automatically for you.

I had an application that got exception only on some devices, and changing the from your code to this code fix it for me on all devices.

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following and it works like a charm.

```
//Base64 basic http authentication
String textToBeEncoded = mName+":"+mPassword;
byte[] data = null;
data = textToBeEncoded.getBytes("UTF-8");
encoding = Base64.encodeToString(data,Base64.NO_WRAP);
Log.d(TAG,"encoded string: "+encoding);
//--------------------------------
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet("//REQUEST URL//");
httpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encoding);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
```

Try using this way instead..

Hope it works.